# Symfony2: Unknown MySQL server host

Tags: php, mysql, symfony

I struggle connecting my first Symfony App with the online database ( ovh ).
Here is the parameters.yml file:

```
parameters:
    database_host: flibustiyxfolio.mysql.db
    database_port: 3306
    database_name: flibustiyxfolio
    database_user: flibustiyxfolio
    database_password: ***********
```

I have no clue why it says that it's unknown, is there anything wrong, I need some help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackoverflow, please visit the [How to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) section of this website...

Comment: What errors are you getting? If not on screen, then look at the error logs. Remember we are not **clairvoyant** and we cannot see **over your shoulder**

Comment: like the title:  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2005] Unknown MySQL server host 'flibustiyxfolio.mysql.db' (2)
500 Internal Server Error - PDOException

Comment: flibustiyxfolio.mysql.db looks like made up hostname, read documentation or contact support of your hosting and ask what's the hostname of mysql server

Comment: well all the params are just fine because I tried to connect from another platform and it works , i think it's more about the symfony config or compatibility with OVH or something I probably missed in deploying the app... thanks for the help anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out, it's again the cache issue in prod env the problem... As I couldn't run the "cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug" command on the server I had to delete all the cache files and it finally worked.